# What metallurgy advancement allowed the transition from mail hauberk to plate armor?

Tags: military, middle-ages, warfare, technology, armour

Why did it happen in the 14th century, when the blast furnace was invented much earlier? Can someone explain, how medieval blacksmiths figured it out? What discovery enabled them to create plate armors?

Comment: Are you sure it was metallurgic advancements and not military necessity? You might want to rephrase to reflect that. I thought this transition was necessitated by advancements and prevalence of firearms. Combine this with the emergence of professional or mercenary armies, as opposed to prior levy armies.

Comment: Well, why wouldn't the medieval nobility in 11th use full plate, if the only problem was just a military necessity? I was of opinion, that the blacksmiths couldn't produce it back then. That they weren't able to create a bigger plates into a usable armor.

Comment: Because it would have been expensive and not needed? I don't think you had massed crossbows or firearms in the 11th, and longbows would be impractical for most kingdoms. 11th century also had peasant levies ie poorly armed and untrained mobs. In the 14th and 15th you start to see large mercenary armies and an emerging professional soldier.

Comment: Plate armor has all kinds of disadvantages... ever tried to wear one? You wouldn't want to, unless opposing weapons force you to.

Comment: @Jotunn It took a long time for well designed, flexible plate armour to appear. But that's not metallurgy though. Also, it was extremely expensive - even the nobility did not have unlimited money.

Comment: So the only reason people didn't use plate armor was because it was expensive and wasn't needed against spears, axes, arrows and swords? 

And I don't think I wouldn't want to wear an armor, that renders almost all projectiles and weapons ineffective. There are also many videos where is shown that a full plate armor is not as immobile as people tend to believe.

Comment: @Jotunn Later plate armour did get much more flexible, but early ones were very burdensome to wear. Plate armour gave great protection but not invulnerability, so it was a significant tactical handicap. The French had plate armour at [Agincourt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Agincourt) and look how much good it did them against English longbows (it didn't). Production *was* a problem, but cost-effectiveness would've been the main constraint.

Comment: I believe skill and need drove plate advancement, not technology.  Romans had a form of full plate (Lorica segmentata) and I'm pretty sure the tech used behind plate mail (at least from a metallurgy standpoint) was around far prior.  I also believe it follows the usage of some weaponry...mail was pretty ineffective vs a flail or morning star compared to full plate.  When weapons required full plate to stop them became common, then full plate became more common.   There's a stepping stone https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mail_and_plate_armour mail and plate armours that encorporate plate into mail

Comment: Most armed men will not be on horses, you need to carry it while walking for miles. Assuming you have horses to carry your gear, your army now has a large and vulnerable baggage train. Marching in the mud and rain is not good for your gear.  So when deciding gear you need to factor weight, ease of use, maintainability, cost, necessity, accessibility, and familiarity into the equation. This is the same reason why some soldiers got flak armor in WW2 and most did not. Even if you are on horseback you need a good horse, good saddle, and stirrups. This tech and breeding was not always available.

Comment: Earliest suit of what I'd fully call plate comes from the Sassanid empires around 600 BC.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clibanarii    "All the companies were clad in iron, and all parts of their bodies were covered with thick plates, so fitted that the stiff-joints conformed with those of their limbs; and the forms of human faces were so skilfully fitted to their heads, that since their entire body was covered with metal, arrows that fell upon them could lodge only where they could see a little through tiny openings opposite the pupil of the eye, or where through the tip of their nose...

Answer (score 21):

The emergence of [late medieval full plate armour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gothic_plate_armour) wasn't really prompted by any specific discovery or advancement in metallurgical tech. Partial plate armour, in principle, can be traced all the way back to Classical Antiquity, such as the [Greek muscle cuirass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muscle_cuirass) later [Roman *lorica segmentata*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorica_segmentata).

Rather, the most critical development was the appearance of larger bloomeries. It was no coincidence that plate armour began in North Italy shortly after such bloomeries appeared there - they made it possible to produce sufficiently large steel plates in one piece.

> The suit of armour of large articulated plates first appears in 14th century Italy, followed later by Germany and the rest of Europe. This was a result of bloomeries having grown large enough to produce metal plates of the required size.
>
> **<sub>Williams, Alan. "The Metallurgy of Medieval European Armour." *Proceedings of the Forum of the 4th International Conference on the Beginning of the Use of Metals and Alloys*. Shimane, Japan, 1996.</sub>**

The problem before this was that you need quite a sizeable amount of steel, about 10kg, for a breastplate. Prior to the late 13th century or so, European bloomeries were generally not large enough to produce so much steel in a single chunk. To make a steel breastplate then, you'd have to weld two or more separate plates together, which compromised its protective value despite an enormous price tag.

> A plate of armour which weighs between 2.5 and 4.5 kg will pose new problems lo the producers. Billets of metal of 10kg or more may be needed to make such a plate
>
> **<sub>Williams, Alan R. *The Knight and the Blast Furnace: A History of the Metallurgy of Armour in the Middle Ages & the Early Modern Period.* Brill, 2003.</sub>**

A significant factor behind the rise of larger bloomeries was that Late Medieval Europe began harnessing the power of rivers - using waterwheels to power furnace bellows enabled larger blooms of steel to be produced.

Once decent full plate armour became feasible to create,  the main obstacle to adoption - aside from a lack of need early on - was simple economics. A full set of plate armour was extremely labour intensive to forge, and consequently very expensive. Keep in mind, even the Romans had to abandon the *lorica segmentata* after the [Crisis of the Third Century](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crisis_of_the_Third_Century) rendered it economically and logistically unsustainable. No military in medieval Europe could rival the Roman Empire's resources.

By the 14th century, however, smiths had begun using watermills to driver hammers for shaping the steel, greatly reduced the labour required.

> Water-power enabled smiths to increase their output. Bellows driven by a waterwheel could produce a continuous powerful draught from a free energy source, so it was at last possible to enlarge the size of the furnace and the bloom thus produced. Water-powered hammers were also heavy enough to fashion the larger blooms.
>
> **<sub>Blair, John, W. John Blair, and Nigel Ramsay, eds. *English Medieval Industries: Craftsmen, Techniques, Products.* A&C Black, 1991.</sub>**

It was the newfound relative affordability of plate armour, combined with improved designs reducing its tactical downsides, that ultimately enabled its adoption. The full plate armour reached its peak about the same time advancements in projectile weaponry began to render it obsolete, however.

Comment: I thought it was because of crossbows. While mail armor can't stop arrows from a crossbows, plate armor is more likely to do it

Comment: @Mandrill The need for protection *drove* the adoption of plate armour, but it doesn't *enable* plate armour to be created, which I think is what the question is asking about.

Comment: +1. The increased need for protection made the cost of plate armor worth paying (standard arms race in play). Increased production volume of plate armor allowed improvements in technology, which drove costs lower, and adoption wider (standard market forces in play).

Comment: Remember that armor did not evolve from chainmail to plate directly but through various transitional phases (at least in Europe).  You can check out 'coat of plates' and brigandine armor on wikipedia.